# How to know which version gradlescript is using to build android app

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I am using below line to build android support libraries:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
```

This line is getting built correctly in Android Studio

I have found current releases for support libraries and they are 26.0.0,26.0.1,26.0.2 & 26.1.0 when I am specifying as below gradle script is not getting build.

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
```

etc, so if I have specified as:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
```

Then how to know which version of 26.+ the gradlescript is using for building the current app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to know the version.

- **command + O** : search a class such as `SwitchCompact` or `RecyclerView`
- Then click the button
  [image]
- Finally you will see

  [image]

By changing Android->Project view(in dropdown list) in Project explorer we can get External Libraries section at bottom there we can find exactly which version is used by gradescript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `+` to specify the `version` of `dependency` then android studio will automatically takes the `newest` version of that `dependency`

Comment: Yes, But how to know exactly which of the latest version(26.X.X) gradlescript is using

Comment: @NikhileshPatve The latest version of appcompact dependency is 26.1.0

Comment: @NikhileshPatve If your Android Studio is connected to internet and if you press gradle sync button android studio will automatically download the latest version for your app. You can check out the release note here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: @NikhileshPatve In your case the problem is you may be using different versions of dependency in your project (like appcompact 26.0.1 and recyclerview 26.1.0 ). Google android dependency version should be same for an application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am expecting answer like instead of cosidering that gradlescript will use latest version. I am expecting like in XYZ folder of build you can verify the dependency version n all exactly that this version buildscript is using,So from which build folder of app we can verify that?